# Simple relation with amount of items

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-relationship, database-schema

I have a project in which I'm simulating db of users in some game. Each user has Equipment, which stores items. Now I'd like to add table storing amount of each item in each users equipment but I'm not quite sure how should look the relation between Equipment|Equipment_items|Items_amount tables. Here's the scheme from Visio:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like the Visio diagram uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something but why would you have three tables?  I would think that you'd have an Item table, a User table, and a User_Item intersection table which included the number of items.  Something like

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  item_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  item_name VARCHAR2(100),
  <<some other attributes>>
);

CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name VARCHAR2(30),
  <<some other attributes
);

CREATE TABLE user_item (
  user_item_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id      NUMBER REFERENCES user( user_id ),
  item_id      NUMBER REFERENCES item( item_id ),
  quantity_held NUMBER
);
```

It sounds like a user's equipment is just the result of the query (i.e. 3 broadswords, 1 chalice, 2 healing potions).

```
SELECT item_id, quantity_held
  FROM user_item
 WHERE user_id = <<some user ID>>
```

But perhaps you're thinking that a player has multiple pieces of equipment that each contain items (i.e. a user has a knapsack, a saddle bag, and a pouch and different items in each piece of equipment)?

Comment: Maybe some attributes don't apply.  IE: saddle dag, +20 damage